# How to pick correct version of FontAwesome for Angular using the package

Tags: angular, npm, font-awesome

FontAwesome has released an [Angular specific package](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/angular) and I want to give it a try instead of the usual linkage from a CDN server. According to the instruction, I'm supposed to install it using the [following command](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome).

> # See Compatibility table below to choose correct version
>   $ npm install @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@<version>

The compatibility table states that I'm supposed to use version *0.3.x* if I'm running Angular version *7.x*. Checking the file *package.json*, I can see that I'm using *"@angular/core": "7.2.5"*, which I'm interpreting to version *0.3.2* for FontAwesome. However, running the command

> npm install @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.3.2

resulted in error about no matching version (which indeed [is true](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome)). I've tried a bunch of different combinations with no luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: @Michael Just to verify for slow people like me. Are you saying I actually type in an "x" there to make sure to get the highest revision from version of major 0 and of minor 3?

Comment: Edit: there was a typo in my original comment. I would install the highest version of 0.3.x using `npm install --save @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.3.x`. This will output some warnings about missing peerDependencies, which you should install separately. (and yes, you can copy and paste that command to install the appropriate version for angular 7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using on Angular 8.2.0. Have the following versions in my **package.json**:

```
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.4.0",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.17",
"@fortawesome/free-brans-svg-icons": "^5.8.1",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.8.1"
```

On Angular 7.2.15, the only one difference I had was `"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0"`.

Comment: According to the linked table, Angular 7 is supposed to go with 0.3.x, while Angular 8 is using 0.4.0. as it a typo on your side or is the table specification out of date? It's not backwards compatible? Naaa, shouldn't be, right?

Comment: These options are in my current project which has been upgraded from Angular 7 to Angular 8. Now took a look on the commit when upgrading to Angular 8, and the only package from these which changed was `"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0"`. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure as to why you've interpreted `@angular/core: "7.2.5"` to mean you have to install FontAwesome version `0.3.2`. The 2 here is just the patch version and it's not necessary that FontAwesome even needed to make any changes while angular updated their versions.

You can just install it without specifying the patch version. This will by default install the latest patch version and since you need to use FontAwesome version `0.3.x`, the patch version doesn't really matter anyway. The only requirement here is that the minor version should be `3`.

```
npm install @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.3
```

Comment: @I was misguided by the "x" instead of plain "0". Thanks.